# vsftpd hides certain extensions, how to disable it?

Tags: permissions, vsftpd, selinux

I just enabled `vsftpd` on my laptop (Fedora 18 if that matters and vsftpd version 3.0.2) and tried to connect to it with my Android phone: success!

Still, some minutes later, I stumbled upon a folder with only two photos, while in Nautilus it shows quite a few extra photos and some videos.

This two photos were sent from a friend and the rest (both videos and photos) come from our DLSR camera.

After playing around I noticed that our friends' images are `.jpg` while the photos from the camera are `.JPG`. A quick bash loop and all images are `.jpg`: win! :)

Still, movies coming from the camera are `.MOV` and changing them to `.mov` does not help it. I tried just to change the extension to `.avi` and it does work (though the video is still in mov format)

So I turned into `man 5 vsftpd.conf` and could only find `deny_file` and `hide_file` which by default should be `(None)` according to man page.

Anyway I added them to `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`, restart it and still no videos :S

Any idea what could be wrong?

Ok, I got a pointer, SELinux seems to be the problem, (see comments below). Still, other users will hit this too, so, any clue how to make SELinux not block some files or others?

Comment: Are you sure it is not Android's fault? Could it be that Android does not recognize the formats you mentioned (JPG for jpg, mov or MOV,...) and thus won't diplay the files?

Comment: No, it's vsftpd or someone else within the laptop. The same (doing an ``ls``) does not work on the terminal ftp client on the laptop itself.

Comment: Are you sure you're not (also) changing permission on the files when renaming them? Have you tried disabling SELinux in Fedora to ensure it's not blocking things?

Comment: No, permissions keep the same: 644 user:user the same as the pictures that I can see. I will try disabling SELinux, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thanks techie007, it was ``SELinux``. Setting it to permissive was enough (``setenforce 0`` as root on a terminal).

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally found it:

```
setsebool -P ftpd_full_access 1
```

The `-P` switch makes it permanent.

For some reason `SELinux` only allows a limited access to ftp functionality, the command above tells `SELinux` to allow full access to ftp, *whatever that means...*